# Problem with suspension fork

Tags: mountain-bike, shocks, handling, giant

I am having trouble with my bicycle which is a Giant Terrago FS1.
I have posted a video on YouTube which might help to explain the situation better, as it might be better than words.

Due to the problem, my handlebars wobble and the suspension doesn't work. However, if the fork lowers are pulled forwards as in the linked video,  the suspension will work. Does anyone have some clue regarding what might have happened?

Here is the link to the video:

If you need any further details please do let me know.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles! You'll probably find it helpful to take the [tour] to see how things work round here. We generally prefer self-contained questions with plenty of details, so you're might like to add a little more description to the text.

Comment: Exact model of the shock?  You can get guides here - http://www.srsuntour-cycling.com/service/   If there is no rebuild kit available then it is probably not serviceable.

Comment: I would not ride that bike fork as is.  your braking forces will shock things and could lead to a sudden broken fork and a rapid faceplant.

Comment: If you don't want to put much money in the bike you could get a fixed fork.  It clearly would not handle rough very well but good for light trail and riding around town.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to excessive wear on the bushings in the fork lowers. There is no rebuild kit for that fork that I'm aware of so, your best bet would probably be to replace the fork or if you can get your hands on a second-hand set of lowers for this fork that are in good condition, you could swap them straight over. If there's that much wear on the bushings though, there's probably a build-up of rust on the stanchions abrading them so it'd be better in the long run to just replace the fork as a whole.

Comment: Based on teh state fo the forks, replacing the bike will be likely cheaper than replacing the forks.

Comment: @mattnz Maybe, I'd always replace the part if at all possible. If you go to a small bike shop, they'll quite often have a similar fork in decent condition laying around that you could buy for next to nothing.